# Insulating Interior Wall That Used to be Exterior Wall

Tags: insulation

My home had an extension built in by the previous owner. I am currently insulating the rim joist in the basement and feel cool air coming in from the wall space above that was once an exterior wall, but is now an interior wall. The extension was on built on the 1st floor only so that wall becomes an exterior wall on the 2nd floor. What type of insulation should I be using to insulate that wall space to prevent the cool air from coming into the basement?

Also, not sure if this matters, the extension was built on a crawlspace which I am in the process of insulating/encapsulating with rigid foam and spray foam.

I am currently using a combo of spray foam and rigid foam for the rim joist.

Comment: The issue is at the floor level below the upper wall, or in the second story rim, right? Either resolve it there or attempt to seal the top of the main floor wall.

Comment: I think it would be rather difficult to resolve the issue at the second story rim since all that space is finished. I should seal the top of the main floor wall. However, will it matter if I used batt insulation? or is spray foam the safest bet at this point?